# How to skip an error and in a for loop in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, rvest

I want to web scrap the URLs of pictures in a list of web pages. I tried the following code.

```
library(rvest)

pic_flat = data.frame()

for (i in 7:60){
  # creating a loop for page urls
  link <- paste0("https://www.immobilienscout24.at/regional/wien/wien/wohnung-kaufen/seite-", i)
  page <- read_html(link)
  # scraping href and creating a url
  href <- page %>% html_elements("a.YXjuW") %>% html_attr('href')
  apt_link <- paste0("https://www.immobilienscout24.at",href)
pic_flat = rbind(pic_flat, data.frame(apt_link))
  }

#get the link to the apartment picture
 apt_pic <- data.frame()
 apt <- pic_flat$apt_link

 for(x in apt){   
   picture <- read_html(x) %>% html_element(".CmhTt") %>% html_attr("src")
   apt_pic <- rbind(apt_pic,data.frame(picture))
   }
df_pic <- cbind(pic_flat,data.frame(apt_pic))
```

But some web pages crash in the middle of the iteration. For example:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 502.
```

So I want to skip those web pages and continue with the next web page and scrap available picture URLs to my data frame. How to use `tryCatch` function or any other method, to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a function and then use `tryCatch` or `possibly` to skip the errors.

First create function `f1` to get links to pictures,

```
#function f1
f1 = function(x){
  picture <- x %>% read_html() %>% html_element(".CmhTt") %>% html_attr("src")
}

apt <- pic_flat$apt_link

#now loop by skipping errors
apt_pic = lapply(apt, possibly(f1, NA))
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, it serves my purpose